# HTTPS-enabled Google search and visibility by network administrator

Tags: google-search, privacy

I searched for websites with a keyword, say, "Monkey", using HTTPS-enabled Google Search on my company's machine.

Can the network administrator somehow associate with me:

1. The keyword "Monkey"?
2. The URLs of the searched websites containing the keyword "Monkey"?
3. The contents of the above websites?

Comment: I think it depends less on Google and more on your network’s configuration.

Answer (score 3):

When you access any site via HTTPS, everything but the server's domain name gets hidden from anyone between your browser and the server.

In your case, your search used a URL like

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=monkey
```

(most likely with more name-and-value query parameters like `&name=value`)

All your network administrator can tell is that you made an https request to `www.google.com`. She doesn't even knows you went to `/search`, let alone the query parameters.

The content returned by Google was cryptographed. She couldn't see it (but she could have a general idea of its size).

Comment: Although the "company's machine" could have had any kind of remote desktop/monitoring software running undetected in the background. It could be monitoring browser history (and sending this to another server). It could even be monitoring keystrokes entered into certain applications. :/